# Suggested lifecycle for SSRS web proxy

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I make use of the SQL Server Reporting Service's [web services api](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx) to render reports using the ReportExecutionService proxy in an asp.net web application.

My question is: should I be creating a new instance of the ReportExecutionService proxy each time I generate a report, or is using a singleton instance the recommended approach? (eg. for performance reasons, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What wcf bindings you are going to use? In general - you can reuse proxy, and in single-user single thread application it is a good idea.

But singleton is a bad idea in ASP.NET application - by itself proxies are not thread-safe.

Therefore, you can create proxy and cache it on session layer (is one session = one thread, as I remember this is configurable in ASP.NET).

Comment: While this may be sound advice in general, in our specific use case, it would be (fairly) unlikely that a given user would re-use the same proxy more than once, so I don't think we would benefit much from this approach. I will accept your answer as a general best practice, though.